# Saying "you too"

Tags: conversation

What's the proper way to respond a sendoff like `祝周末愉快` while repeating the same wish to the sender?

In English, we might say something like "Thanks, you too."

Is there a shorter or more appropriate way to express `也祝周末愉快`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The short form:
  谢谢，你也是！ You, too!/The same to you!

---

- The longer form:
  Repeat with 谢谢，我也祝你X, e.g. 谢谢，我也祝你新年快乐！

Comment: Also "同乐" can be used to respond “新年快乐” and other festival greetings.

Comment: I wanted to say 彼此 but I'm not sure if it's right to use in that sense, so I'm making it a comment rather than an answer.